# Can't capture response from paginated API with axios

Tags: javascript, recursion, axios

I'm attempting to use a recursive function to consume an endpoint and I'm having trouble getting to my end data. If I use this:

```
let b0 = []
const paginatedAPI = (uri, arr) => {
  axios.get(uri)
  .then(resp => {
    //console.log(resp.data.info.next)
    arr = [...arr,...resp.data.results]
    //console.log(arr)
    if(resp.data.info.next){
      paginatedAPI(resp.data.info.next,arr)
    }
    return arr
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
  return arr
}

b0 = paginatedAPI('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character',b0)
```

and uncomment the logging statements it's obvious that the array is being filled correctly but of course it's empty when I evaluate it in dev tools. I
first attempted the run with this code that works fine but seems wrong:

```
axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character')
.then(response => {
  console.log(response)
  let numPages = response.data.info.pages
  a0 = [...response.data.results]
  for(let i = 2;i <= numPages;i++){
    axios.get(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=${i}`)
    .then(resp => populateDropDown(a0 = [...a0,...resp.data.results]))
  }
})
.catch(data => {
  const htmlStr = '<div class="text-danger">We\'re sorry, but an unexpected error occurred</div>';
  $('.container').append(htmlStr);
});
```

I've tried googling for a solution that's bare bones but have had no luck so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research and looking at Promises and async/await I still felt I just needed to ***capture*** the data somewhere so I finally tried this:

```
let b0 = []

const paginatedAPI = (uri, arr) => {
   axios.get(uri)
  .then(resp => {
    arr = [...arr,...resp.data.results]
    if(resp.data.info.next){
      paginatedAPI(resp.data.info.next,arr)
    }
    b0 = arr
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
}

paginatedAPI('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character',b0)
```

And it works! Thanks